# C# Excel VSTO add-in - Excel process can't shut down after adding custom task pane

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm trying to fix the issue in my Excel add-in where Excel gets stuck in the process when my user exits Excel.

I noticed that the issue starts to happen after adding a CustomTaskPane, then when I try to close Excel, it doesn't exit completely and stays in Task Manager. However if I close Excel before adding the CustomTaskPane, Excel closes properly.

Here's just a simple code on how I add the CustomTaskPane, it's just a simple blank Task Pane.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var host = new ElementHost();
        host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        var taskPaneControl = new UserControl();
        taskPaneControl.Controls.Add(host);
        var taskPaneValue = CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneControl, "My TaskPane");
        taskPaneValue.Visible = true;
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Office.CommandBar taskBar = null;
        try
        {
            taskBar = Application.CommandBars["Task Pane"];
            taskBar.Reset();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (taskBar != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(taskBar);
                taskBar = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

As for the ThisAddIn_Shutdown method, it doesn't matter whether that function is empty or not, Excel still doesn't close properly.

What's with the issue where Excel does not close properly after adding a CustomTaskPane?

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: AFAIK the task/actions pane has a history of problems like this, and there is a good chance you won't find a good answer. You might try different VSTO versions and/or Office apps/versions. The MSDN forums might have something as well.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to add a task pane is given here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942846.aspx  , also there is no relation with the commandBars so you can delete your code inside shutdown.

```
    private MyUserControl myUserControl1;
    private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
            myUserControl1 = new MyUserControl();
            myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl1, "My Task Pane");
            myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: The answer you gave is to use WinForms in the task pane. I need to use WPF, hence the need to use ElementHost.

Comment: you didn't mention it before. Try to declare your taskPaneControl outside of the scope of the Startup function.

Comment: I had that on another solution, same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why Excel doesn't close after adding a custom taskpane in that way, you need to follow @Malick answer BUT

In a new class that we will call `UserControlWinForm`, you add a host `elementHost1` and put your WPF usercontrol `UserControlWpfMain`

```
public class UserControlWinForm : UserControl
{
    public UserControlWinForm()
    {
        var elementHost1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost();
        elementHost1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Controls.Add(elementHost1);
        var frm = new UserControlWpfMain();
        elementHost1.Child = frm;
    }
}
```

And, following @Malick, you add your Winform usercontrol